# Text is written outside of the card

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

This is a project for monitoring employees and the first interface in this project is the login interface.

When the user presses the registration button, they must verify the email sent to them.

This is a form of verifying the e-mail, but the text is writing outside the card.

How can I solve this problem?

`ConfirmEmail.Vue`:

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout row class="padding mb-7">
      <v-flex xs3 sm5 offset-sm3>
        <v-card
          class="mx-auto mt-5 pa-5 text-center secondary text-no-wrap"
          max-width="1000px"
          max-height="2000px"
          id="limited-products"
          outlined
        >
          <v-btn class="ma-2 icon-size" outlined fab color="blue">
            <v-icon large class="icon-size" color="blue darken-2">
              mdi-email
            </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-layout row class="pt-10">
              <v-flex xs12>
                <div class="text-center phase-style">Verify Your email address</div>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>

              <span class="SeparatorRow LoginDefaultView-separatorRow pt-6"
                ><span class="SeparatorRow-horizontalLine"></span
                ><span class="SeparatorRow-horizontalLine"></span
              ></span>

            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex xs12 xs3 sm5 offset-sm3>
                <div>
                  please confirm your email address,to activate your account. if
                you received this by mistakes or weren't expecting it, please
                disgard this email
                </div>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<style scoped>
.padding {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.icon-size{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.phase-style{
    font-size: 26px;
}
.SeparatorRow {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.SeparatorRow-horizontalLine {
  border-top: 1px solid #e8ecee;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.LoginDefaultView-separatorRowLabel {
  color: #cbd4db !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `v-card` has `no-text-wrap` which is causing your text to be one long line. Assuming that is not there for a good reason, you could remove that in this instance and set a custom class on the `v-card` that has `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow-y: scroll` (vertical scrolling).

```
.confirm-card {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: How can I increase the size of the icon?

Comment: @HibaRRRR on the `v-icon`? You have `large` on it already. You could do the same thing with a custom class on that one if you want and set your heights and widths that way.